# conditional background color in python - new to python

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to write a work script into excel from Python to excel.  I have had to format the size and type of the columns already, but I need one of the columns to have conditional colors.
    ex./
    column A has percentages.
    For all cells < 0%, we need the cells to be red
    For all cells = 0%, we need the cells to be yellow
    For all cells > 0%, we need the cells to be green

And then, the first row of each column needs to be blue.

I've found scripts similar, but they aren't as conditional.

I've tried a few variations of

```
# Light red fill.
format1 = name.add_format({'bg_color':   '#FFC7CE'})

# Light yellow fill.
format2 = name.add_format({'bg_color':   '#FFEB9C'})

# Green fill.
format3 = name.add_format({'bg_color':   '#C6EFCE'})

try:
    sheet1.conditional_format('A:A', {'type': 'cell',
                                      'criteria': '<',
                                      'value': 0,
                                      'format': format1})


    sheet1.conditional_format('A:A', {'type': 'cell',
                                      'criteria': '==',
                                      'value': 0,
                                      'format': format2})

    sheet1.conditional_format('A:A', {'type': 'cell',
                                      'criteria': '>',
                                      'value': 0,
                                      'format': format3})

except AttributeError: 
    sheet1.conditional_format = None

except TypeError:
    type = None
```

but it doesn't change the colors

and I've tried a few variations of

```
while 'BU:BU' != " " :
    if 'BU:BU' < '0%':
        sheet1.style = redFill
    elif 'BU:BU' == '0%':
        sheet1.style = yellowFill
    elif 'BU:BU' > '0%':
        sheet1.style = '#C6EFCE'
    else: 
        pass 

continue
```

but that keeps getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  In order for this to work, the three formats cannot be in the same cell.  Each needs to be in its own with the exceptions.

Also, boundaries need to be put on how many cells it runs on.  If it is something that will be run multiple times with a changing number of rows, you can shoot high.

One cell:

```
# Light red fill.
format1 = name.add_format({'bg_color':   '#FFC7CE'})

try:
    sheet1.conditional_format('A1:A900', {'type': 'cell',
                                      'criteria': '<',
                                      'value': 0,
                                      'format': format1})

except AttributeError: 
    sheet1.conditional_format = None

except TypeError:
    type = None
```

Another cell:

```
# Light yellow fill.
format2 = name.add_format({'bg_color':   '#FFEB9C'})

...
```